# Expo + React Native - PDF Creation & Download

Tags: react-native, expo

Is there a reliable way to create a file (specifically via [Print.printToFileAsync](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/print/#printprinttofileasyncoptions) API), and since it creates the new file in the user's [cacheDirectory](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/sdk/filesystem/#api), copy it across to their documentDirectory - that works in both Android and iOS?

I've come across others trying to do the same thing [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2201), but to no avail.

One solution I've seen is to [use the MediaLibrary API to download the file to the device's CameraRoll](https://forums.expo.io/t/how-to-locates-downloaded-file-on-device/12542) - but this is hacky and doesn't work on iPhone since the file I'm trying to copy/download is a PDF, and not an image/movie.

[Various solutions are listed here too](https://forums.expo.io/t/how-to-save-the-file-to-devices-folder-like-download/2398/5) - but they either don't work, or only work in one OS.

My end goal is to be able to generate a PDF on the device and save it to the user's storage, without needing to send information back to the server.
My app is not ejected as it stands.

Any advice/direction would be appreciated!

**EDIT 1:**

Considering ejecting at some stage, but due to the nature of the project I'm working on I'd prefer to do that right at the end. Also came across [this post which tries to Share the file URI](https://forums.expo.io/t/save-or-export-expo-generated-file-on-android/15725), but this isn't supported on Android.

Comment: Did you find any solution on this? My requirement is similar, and working on both OS as well. But with Android 11, I am facing issue "Unable to Copy file to Storage".

Comment: @Surjeet unfortunately I left the company and don't have access to that code base anymore - but what I ended up doing was getting the base64 code and converting it to a data URL for the browser to open. Seems really silly, but worked perfectly on both Android and IOS

Comment: My requirement is to keep it into storage. So converting to base64 and open in a browser won't work.

Comment: Ah that's unfortunate, I don't have a solution for you - humble apologies :( I would have thought since this post was up that Expo would have rectified this issue in some way

Answer (score 0):

I hope you dont have any problem with creating the pdf,to save the file have you tried

https://github.com/Lyrillind/react-native-file-manager

it supports both anroid and ios.

If you want you can build your own native module to save the file ,

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#content

Comment: but will it work for expo, because native modules are not available in expo